# Can I reduce how Mobile Safari refreshes web pages when multi-tasking or browsing in multiple tabs?

Tags: iphone, web-browsing

Whenever i visit a page using the web browser, then i simply jump to other applications, when i come back to the page again, the web browser will reload the url.

Is there anyway to make it such that if i come back to the page again, simply show me whatever was shown previously, without any reloads whatsoever.

I've noticed this problem to occur when i was switching tabs in the web browser as well. let's say I have 3 tabs, then i was at tab 1. then later i jump to tab 3, I do not wish to issue a page refresh.

How do we stop iphone from automatically performing all these annoying page reloads?

Comment: Nothing useful for you now, but as I understand it, iOS 5 does a better job at managing this kind of thing. Of course, you're still limited by the RAM on the device, so sooner-or-later you have to page things out of memory.

Comment: @Kerri - "Page things out of memory". This is interesting. If Safari did *memory paging* to the storage in this case (like computers do), then we would not have these annoying page reloadings.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the *real* solution is to **use Chrome on iPhone**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to change the virtual memory if you jailbreak the iOS, but even if you could, it might not be a good idea.

What you can control is everything else. If you prevent the system from needing RAM by closing all of the other apps in the muti-tasking bar before starting safari, the chance that those web renders will get paged out of RAM is less.

Do be aware, that the newer hardware has larger RAM - so the iPad 2 in practice keeps all 9 web pages in RAM much more regularly than the iPad will. If this is important, you will want to get devices with more RAM (test them in the store before buying) or severely control the apps that you do run.

Comment: is it that once i open alot of apps the browser loses the "cached pages" or is it only just before when i open the web browser AND there is not enough ram that the "cached pages" gets thrown away?

Comment: So - on my iPhone - I still have a cached page from sunday morning. I have 8 tabs open and nothing is refreshing. You have to run enough apps and processes to fill up the RAM for the system to send a low memory warning. Safari (AFAIK) doesn't just expire pages, it waits for a message from the system to free up the pages. I suppose a page that set itself to expire might get refreshed sooner. It's not a trivial thing - there are a lot of moving pieces to consider.

Comment: no i was actually wondering: i now have 9 tabs. i minimize browser. i open some apps which sucks tons of ram. i close those apps later. i open my browser again. is it that the pages will still be there (unrefreshed) or is it that the instance the ram-heavy app uses up the ram it's already gone (so even if after i have finished using the ram heavy app AND close it, the pages are still lost when i run browser?)

Comment: @Pacerier - In this case, heavy chances are that the pages in Safari *will be reloaded*.

Answer (score 8):

What you're experiencing is the iPhone flushing pages from RAM to free up memory. There's no way to prevent this from happening, but some things that can alleviate it are keeping less pages open, and being mindful of the current number of apps that you're using that are taking up memory. As iOS needs memory for the current app, it'll kill off less recently used apps/pages.

Comment: so there's no way to mark which apps (actually just the browser) i absolutely do not wish their memory wiped from?

Comment: Web pages that are expected to persist need to be designed to run as an off line web app. See http://www.apple.com/webapps/index_sp.html for a collection of web pages that will persist better because they were programmed to persist. Your pages you want might be set to expire to drive ad revenue?

Comment: @Pacerier not on stock iOS, no. might be possible with jailbreaking. there are a number of apps that do save pages for offline viewing, Instapaper, Wikipanion, etc, depending on the content you're viewing.

Comment: @bmike - About the "off-line Web apps". The link is broken. Do you have a source for that? What can a Web author do to have the page persist?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Books have been written on that topic. Here is a primer... https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html